# Smooth Div Scroll with Colorbox - Gallery

Tags: html, scroll, colorbox, image-gallery, smoothing

I'm having one issue with the Smooth Div Control.  I think it is something minor.

I have four galleries on the main page now all using the Smooth Div Scroll. Some images are placeholders, but I just want to make sure the gallery is functioning. I cannot understand why the fourth scrollable gallery is coming in different and larger than the first three?

Here is the link again: 
http://www.gerardtonti.com/Scrollable%20Gallery%202/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>

<!-- the CSS for Smooth Div Scroll -->
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothDivScroll.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css" />

<!-- Styles for my specific scrolling content -->
<style type="text/css">

#makeMeScrollable
{
    width:100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea a
{
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#makeMeScrollable2
{
    width:100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
#makeMeScrollable2 div.scrollableArea a
{
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#makeMeScrollable3
{
    width:100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
#makeMeScrollable3 div.scrollableArea a
{
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}​

#makeMeScrollable4
{
    width:100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
#makeMeScrollable4 div.scrollableArea a
{
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}​

</style>

</head>

<body>
<style css="text/css">
body {background-color: black; background-image:url("images/background.jpg");    background-repeat: repeat}
</style>


<img src="images/FineArt.png">

<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <a href="images/paintings/Nude_Big.jpg"><img src="images/paintings/Nude.jpg" alt="Nude" id="field" width="330" height="330" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/paintings/Walter_Big.jpg"><img src="images/paintings/Walter.jpg" alt="Walter" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/paintings/OneOfUs_Big.jpg"><img src="images/paintings/OneOfUs.jpg" alt="One Of Us" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
</div>
<img src="images/PublicArt.png">

<div id="makeMeScrollable2">
    <a href="images/publicart/Elevate1_Big.jpg"><img src="images/publicart/Elevate1.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
</div>
<img src="images/CoffeeHouse.png">

<div id="makeMeScrollable3">
    <a href="images/coffeepaintings/TazzaDoro_Big.jpg"><img src="images/coffeepaintings/TazzaDoro.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
</div>

<img src="images/Portraits.png">

<div id="makeMeScrollable4">
    <a href="images/portraits/Erin_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/Erin.jpg" alt="Erin" id="Erin" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/ErinColor_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/ErinColor.jpg" alt="Erin Color" id="Erin Color" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/Robert_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/Robert.jpg" alt="Robert" id="Robert" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/Scott_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/Scott.jpg" alt="Scott" id="Scott" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/Sean_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/Sean.jpg" alt="Sean" id="Sean" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/Nate_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/Nate.jpg" alt="Nate" id="Nate" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/Bill_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/Bill.jpg" alt="Bill" id="Bill" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/Erin3_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/Erin3.jpg" alt="Erin3" id="Erin3" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
    <a href="images/portraits/Erin4_Big.jpg"><img src="images/portraits/Erin4.jpg" alt="Erin4" id="Erin4" /><img src="images/spacer.png" width="15"></a>
</div>

<!-- LOAD JAVASCRIPT LATE - JUST BEFORE THE BODY TAG 
     That way the browser will have loaded the images
     and will know the width of the images. No need to
     specify the width in the CSS or inline. -->

<!-- jQuery library - Please load it from Google API's -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI Widget and Effects Core (custom download)
You can make your own at: http://jqueryui.com/download -->
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Latest version of jQuery Mouse Wheel by Brandon Aaron
 You will find it here: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos -->
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery Kinetic - for touch -->
<script src="js/jquery.kinetic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Smooth Div Scroll 1.3 minified-->
<script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- If you want to look at the uncompressed version you find it at
 js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js -->
<!-- Colorbox -->
<script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- If you want to look at the uncompressed version you find it at
     js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js -->

<!-- Plugin initialization -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// Init Smooth Div Scroll   
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
manualContinuousScrolling: true,
autoScrollingMode: "onStart",
autoScrollingDirection:"endlessLoopRight"
});
$("#makeMeScrollable2").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
    manualContinuousScrolling: true,
    autoScrollingMode: "onStart",
    autoScrollingDirection:"endlessLoopLeft"
});
$("#makeMeScrollable3").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
    manualContinuousScrolling: true,
    autoScrollingMode: "onStart",
    autoScrollingDirection:"endlessLoopRight"
});
$("#makeMeScrollable4").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
    manualContinuousScrolling: true,
    autoScrollingMode: "onStart",
    autoScrollingDirection:"endlessLoopLeft"
});


// Init colorbox
$("#makeMeScrollable a").colorbox({ speed: "500" });
$("#makeMeScrollable2 a").colorbox({ speed: "500" });
$("#makeMeScrollable3 a").colorbox({ speed: "500" });
$("#makeMeScrollable4 a").colorbox({ speed: "500" });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with your `css styles` section:

```
#makeMeScrollable3 div.scrollableArea a
{
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}â€‹ //here

#makeMeScrollable4 div.scrollableArea a
{
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}â€‹ //here
```